# Adding and Setting Ranges in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have this sample table.

[image]

What I am trying to do is to get all the cell values in all colored cells and transpose them to another worksheet. 
I have trouble with the code below to add and set those ranges together so that I can transpose all of them in a ROW in the other worksheet. I have started with the code below

```
Sub AddRanges()

Dim inRange As Range, inRangeValues() As Variant, outRangeValues() As Variant
Dim finalRow As Long
Dim inRange As Range


Set inRange = Sheet1.Range("A1:A6", "C1:C6", C10:C14) 'I think i got this wrong; Error Type Mismatch

inRangeValues() = inRange.Value 'generate 2d array
outRangeValues = Application.Transpose(inRangeValues)

With Sheet2 
    finalRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'find last row

    If inRange.Columns.Count > 1 Then        '2d array for output
        .Cells(finalRow + 1, 1).Resize(UBound(outRangeValues, 1), UBound(outRangeValues, 2)) = outRangeValues 'Resize according to output array dimensions
    Else                                     '1D array for output
        .Cells(finalRow + 1, 1).Resize(1, UBound(outRangeValues, 1)) = outRangeValues
    End If
End With
End sub
```

In this example, what is the best approach to combine these ranges so I can transpose them as a ROW? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by Transposing them into one column? If you want them in one column, that would not by transposing since the data is already in columns.

Comment: Sorry, I corrected it. I mean row not column.

Comment: People have taken the time to answer your question, you need to take the time to select an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has major problems due to:

- Double declaration of `inRange`
- Wrong syntax for `Set inRange` *the entire address needs to be enclosed in a single pair of quotes*

  - Try `Set inRange = Range("a1:a6, c1:c6, c10:c14")`
- Wrong method of reading into an array

When you have a range that consists of multiple areas, you have to convert each area separately.

Then you can create a 1-D array from this depending on the order you wish to have these elements, and write it wherever you want.

For example:

```
Option Explicit
Sub test()
    Dim inRange As Range, inRangeValues As Variant, outRangeValues As Variant
    Dim finalRow As Long
    Dim I As Long, J As Long, V As Variant, L As Long
    Dim lCols As Long

Set inRange = Range("a1:a6, c1:c6, c10:c14")

ReDim inRangeValues(1 To inRange.Areas.Count)
For I = 1 To inRange.Areas.Count
    inRangeValues(I) = inRange.Areas(I)
Next I

'how many columns?
lCols = 0
 For I = 1 To UBound(inRangeValues, 1)
    lCols = lCols + UBound(inRangeValues(I), 1)
 Next I

ReDim outRangeValues(1 To lCols)

L = 0
For I = 1 To UBound(inRangeValues, 1)
    For J = 1 To UBound(inRangeValues(I), 1)
        L = L + 1
        outRangeValues(L) = inRangeValues(I)(J, 1)
    Next J
Next I

Stop

   ' enter some code to write the results where you want
   ' below is just throwaway for proof of concept

Range("f20").Resize(columnsize:=UBound(outRangeValues)).Value = outRangeValues


End Sub
```

Given your input, the above code would  create output like:

[image]

Comment: I really appreciate your suggestion and i am hoping I can make this work. However, I am a newbie and learning along the way. If you can Please continue the code as I was really stuck on that part I will highly appreciate your answer. Also, I am hoping to have the output be placed on the lastrow of the next worksheet. Thanks.

Comment: @Synod It's just a matter of changing `Range("f20")…` to wherever you want.  If you want it on the last row of the next worksheet, the something like `wsNext.Cells(wsNext.Rows.Count,1).Resize(columnsize:=uBound(outRangeValues)).Value = outRangeValue`.  If you mean the last **empty** row, then something like `wsNext.Cells(wsNext.Rows.Count,1).End(xlup).Offset(1,0).Resize(….`

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that your code is wrong where you highlight. Try a `union`. From there, it should be pretty basic to just loop through your range and put them wherever you want in the Sheet2 spreadsheet. See if the below does what you need.

```
  Sub AddRanges()

Dim inRange As Range, acell As Range, aCounter As Long
Const startAddress As String = "A1"

Set inRange = Union(Sheet1.Range("A1:A6"), Sheet1.Range("C1:C6"), Sheet1.Range("C10:C14"))

For Each acell In inRange.Cells

    If Not IsEmpty(acell) Then

    finalRow = sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1 'find last row

    sheet2.Cells(finalRow, 1).Value = acell.Value
    End If


Next acell
End Sub
```

Comment: I didn't mean that the list must start at A1 every time the code starts. What I meant that in using your code, it starts in the top-left most part. Further, when I use your code, the results appeared in a column after the finalRow. As I have asked, It must appear as a row.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Check it out.

```
Sub RngAreaTransps()

    Dim RangeArea As Range, LstRw As Long
    Dim sh As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet
    Dim col As Long, InRange As Range

    Set sh = Sheets(1)
    Set ws = Sheets(2)
    LstRw = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    With sh
        Set InRange = .Range("A1:A6, C1:C6, C10:C14")

        For Each RangeArea In InRange.Areas

            With ws

                col = .Cells(LstRw, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
                If col <> 1 Then col = col + 1
                RangeArea.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Copy
                .Cells(LstRw, col).PasteSpecial Transpose:=True

            End With

        Next RangeArea

    End With

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, before I start checking your suggestion I am thinking that probably the code will let me place the values in a column. if so, I am sorry but I corrected by question that I am trying to place it in the last row of the second sheet. Thanks.

Comment: I tested your code, but i am having a runtime error code 1004 by at the start of "For Each RangeArea In InRange.Areas". Do I need to define(?) RangeArea first?

Comment: The code works as is. Where have you placed the code?

Comment: Sorry, I tried it and works well. However, I am just wondering what is it in the code that does not consider blanks. Further, although minor already, It does not go to the next finalrow. Thanks. It leads me to a new option.

Comment: SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants). copies just the cells with values.Code has been edited to paste to next row.